# Get rowid value with datatables when using pure json input

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

In my project I use datatables to display data directly form the database. My input data is pure JSON and I never used any of back end processing methods mentioned in the datatables website

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {

        "order": [[ -0 ]],
        "pageLength": 24,
        "oLanguage": { "sSearch": '<a class="btn searchBtn" id="searchBtn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>' },
        "lengthChange": false,

        "ajax": {
            "url": "data.php?content=userdata",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },

        "columns": [            
            { "data": "id",
               "visible": false,
            },
            { "data": "oid" },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "mobile" },
            { "data": "email" },
            { "data": null,
                "targets": -0,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<button>test</button>",
            }
        ],

    } );

    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
        var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        alert("oid is: "+ data[ 1] );
    } );
} );
```

and my JSON input is like this

```
[
    {
    id: "3",
    oid: "213",
    name: "Koh Tien Kit Thomas ",
    mobile: 0123456789,
    email: "some@mail.com",
    }
]
```

but when I click the datatable row button, It saying value is undefined. my json not include the data object as datatables site mentioning. how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API method [`row().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()) returns data in the original format. Since you used objects, OID would be available in `data['oid']` .

Use the code below instead:

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
    var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    alert("oid is: "+ data['oid'] );
} );
```